# Voice Recognition using python 2.7 in windows 10

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-10, voice-recognition, simplecv

I am using python2.7 in my 64 bit Windows10 system. I am working on SimpleCV framework and i want to implement voice recognition to control my vlc media player. Is there any module in SimpleCv or in python2.7 through which i can easily implement voice recognition.If so,please guide me through the produre. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Let me begin by saying that I recommend using Python 3 and above, if possible.

Currently I'm developing a Python 3 open-source cross-platform virtual assistant program called Athena Voice: https://github.com/athena-voice/athena-voice-client

Users can use it much like Siri, Cortana, or Amazon Echo.

It also uses a very simple "module" system where users can easily write their own modules to enhance it's functionality. It would be easy to write a VLC module which lets you control VLC with your voice.

Otherwise, I recommend looking into Pocketsphinx. Pocketsphinx is an offline open-source voice recognition program. It's great for detecting key words/phrases (like commands).

However, I use it solely as a "wake-up-word" engine. I let pocketsphinx passively listen for the word "athena" to be woken up. Once activated, I use Google's Python speech-to-text engine to listen (more accurately) for a command.

I recommend looking into Google's Python speech-to-text and text-to-speech packages.

Both packages can be installed by using the command:

```
pip install SpeechRecognition gTTS
```

Google STT: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Google TTS: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gTTS/1.0.2

Pocketsphinx can be pretty complicated to set up. I'd try installing the dependencies listed here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python

Then try using:

```
pip install pocketsphinx
```

Pocketsphinx and Google STT have PyAudio as a dependency which can be found here (unofficial): http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am looking forward to it.